# Python IndexError after output

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-requests-html

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/')
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup (c, 'html.parser')

indexs = 0
table1 = soup.find("table")
table2 = table1.find('tbody')
table3 = table2.find_all('td')
for index,i in enumerate(table3):
    print(f'{index} - {table3[indexs].text} - Total Cased - {table3[indexs+1].text}')
    indexs+=9
```

hello guys i have problem, this code making his job Awesome outputing what just it should but at the end when it output last one saying error like this

```
Exception has occurred: IndexError
list index out of range
  File "C:\Users\SGamr\Desktop\Python\worldmetters.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(f'{index} - {table3[indexs].text} - Total Cased - {table3[indexs+1].text}')
```

help me , Thanks <3

Comment: What is your question? “Help me” is not a question. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: @amc Getting error after output and i dont know what to do

Comment: You don’t know what to do? What do you usually do when you encounter a problem?

Comment: Trying to fix it

Comment: Go on.... How do you do that?

Comment: trying to get info about error why it is exsist and changing code ahaha

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")[0]

df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```

Output: [Check-online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/0db6a5181751122d6fb15ee36ccee072/result.csv)

[image]